# Why can't I pass the props down with an array

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React so please bear with me! I Believe the reason for this is due to the lifecycle method, as this is rendering before the state is updated.
I am trying to learn Hook but I can't seem to see what im doing wrong.

I have a file with an array full of objects which is in my main state. I have then created another file called "Questions". The "choices" Should be an array but this is rendering before the details are passed. I have attempted the "useEffect" but it goes in to a continuing loop. if I pass an empty bracket at the end, well Im in the same position, it renders before the state is passed down. What can I do?

tried useEffect with no joy.

```
    //top file with state 


    import React, { Component,useState,useEffect } from "react";
    import axios from 'axios'
    import Questions from './Questions'
    import Data from '../Data/Data'
    class Main extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state={
            nxt:0

        }

    }

    pushData=()=>{
      const {nxt}=this.state;
      this.setState({
          question:Data[nxt].question,
          choices:[Data[0].choice1,Data[0].choice2,Data[0].choice3],
          answer:Data[nxt].answer


      })

    }



    componentDidMount(){
    this.pushData()
    }


    render() {
    const {question,choices,answer}=this.state

    return (
      <div>
    <Questions choices={choices} question={question}/>


      </div>
    )


    }
    }
    export default Main



    import React, { Component,useState,useEffect } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


    const Questions=({question,choices})=>{

      const [theChoices,setTheChoices] = useState(choices)
    console.log(theChoices,choices)
      return (
        <div>
    <h3>{question} </h3>
    {
    theChoices.map(item => (<h3>{item}</h3>) )
    }
    </div>

    )
    }

    export default Questions
```

I want the array in choices to list

Comment: Can you format your code a bit better? It's quite hard to follow the poor indentation

Comment: Why do you need `theChoices` state inside Questions component? Use directly `choices` instead and it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm new to hooks, but could you explain why "theChoice" don't work when i've passed it as an argument with useState?

Comment: The argument of useState, is only used on first render to give a default value to your  variable `theChoices`. Since on first render `choices`is an empty array, then `theChoices` will be an empty array until you change its value using the appropriate setter `setTheChoices`.

Answer (score 2):

`questions`, `choices` and `answers` are `undefined` in the first render. Declare it inside initial state

```
this.state = {
    nxt: 0,
    questions: [],
    answers: [],
    choices : []
}
```

Update

**Why is that the case?**

In the first render (before `componentDidMount`) you are trying to pass down to `Questions` two `props` calleed `qustions` and `choices`. The problem is, until `pushData()` get's called this properties don't exist in Main's `state` (just `nxt`). So inside `Question` you're tryind to use `.map()` in `undefined`

**Why doesn't "theChoices" work when I use useState with the state as an argument?**

The parameter passed to `useState` is the `initial` value. If you pass a `prop` as initial value it's just that, initial. It won't react to any changes of that `prop`. In class components we work around this by using `componentDidUpdate` or even `getDerivedStateFromProps`. In functional components you could add an effect to update the state everytime the `prop` changes

```
useEffect(() =>{
    setTheChoices(choices)
},[choices])
```

Comment: Thank you so much that appears to work. Could you explain 2 things for me please,  firstly why is that the case?
And also, the below works, but why doesn't "theChoices" work when i use useState with the state as an arguement?


const Questions=({question,choices})=>{

          const [theChoices,setTheChoices] = useState(choices)
        console.log(theChoices,choices)
          return (
            <div>
        <h3>{question} </h3>
        {
        choices.map(item => (<h3>{item}</h3>) )
        }
        </div>

        )
        }

Comment: `useState(choices)`,  `theChoices`  is initialised on first render with `choices`, which is empty  on first render. Thereafter the only way to mutate `theChoices` is to to use the setter `setTheChoices`.

Comment: i'm updating the answer

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Thank you so much